# Remove sensitive data from typesscript files using webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have a build setup where I use webpack as bundler and most data is in typescript which is loaded using webpack loader. I want to removed ertain data from the files based on environment variable or any other technuiqe which does't leave any trace or prevent me from debugging the files.

Comment: If the data can be removed without affecting debugging, why is it in there in the first place?

Comment: you might want to explorer dontEnv for data to be shown for environment specific information

Comment: Based on the environment. I want to remove certain data from the file.